# Concurrent writing to multiple files using asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

What is the design pattern for writing to multiple files using `asyncio`?

Here's the outline of the single-threaded version of what I want to do.

```
import datetime
import json

def generate_records():
   for i in range(100):
       # simulate some JSON content that I want to write to a file
       # assume that this takes some significant amount of time
       yield {
         'index':index,
         'message':f"Message {index}",
         'timestamp':datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
       }



for (i,r) in enumerate(generate_records()):
    with open(f"record_{i:04}.json", 'w') as fout:
         json.dump(r, fout)
```

How does one utilize `asyncio` to write these files concurrently with the generation of the records?

Comment: `asyncio` should be used with an event loop so that a single thread could accept write requests to different files (which is considered slow I/O) asynchronously. See https://codeflex.co/python3-async-await-example/?amp

Comment: Writing asynchronously to the same disk does not improve overall performance.

Comment: @yoonghm the goal is to be able to write to disk concurrently with iterating over the data.  I tried to keep the example simple in order to keep it focused on the asyncio part.  Updated to better reflect what I'm getting at.

Comment: @yoonghm: It can actually, at least for spinning disks; if the OS has multiple writes queued, it can reorder them so they're written in order as the drive head performs a single pass from inside to outside of the disk (or vice-versa). Imagine if a disk had tracks ABCDEFGH from inside to outside; if the drive head is at A and you write to B, D and F concurrently, it can do the writes in a single scan. Sequential writes to F, then B, then D incur higher seek latency. Admittedly, barring `sync` calls, the OS is typically caching writes and reordering them anyway, but improved perf is *possible*.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, disk drive technology has caught up on me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json
import datetime
import aiofiles

async def main():
    def mk_record(index):
        # simulate some JSON content that I want to write to a file
        return {
            'index': index,
            'message': f"Message {index}",
            'timestamp': datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
        }
    records = [mk_record(i) for i in range(100)]

    async def write_record(i, r):
        # Test by pretending the write takes a while
        # Delete this line for actual code.
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        async with aiofiles.open(f'/tmp/record_{i:04}.json', mode='w') as fout:
            await fout.write(json.dumps(r))

    await asyncio.gather(*[write_record(i, r) for i, r in enumerate(records)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Uh.  Sorry.  My original answer had a mistake in it and I had to fix it.  The writing of the records was still happening one after.  I realized I had to change it so that writing each record was a separate task.  Fixed above.